# Déterminer l'équation de la tangente à la courbe C, parallèle à la droite d

Tags: calculus

Soit $C$ une courbe d'équation $f(x)=\frac43x^3+2x²+3x+7$ et d une droite d'équation $y-2x+3=0$.

**Translation**

**Title** Determine the equation of the tangent to the curve $C$ which is parallel to the line $d$

Let $C$ be the curve of equation $f(x)=\frac43x^3+2x^2+3x+7$ and $d$ the line of equation $y-2x+3=0$.

Comment: On Math Stack Exchange everyone writes in english, and you should do it too

Comment: questions en francais sont bienvenues ici http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1617/what-is-the-site-etiquette-about-i-asking-and-ii-answering-questions-in-a-la / questions in French are welcome here.

Comment: @mt_. Everyone is welcome here but we have the chance to have a common language almost accepted everywhere : English. Why then should be avoid posts in Eskimo or in Papuan or written in hieroglyphs ? May I add that I am a Frenchman.

Comment: With a translation, any language is welcome here (thanks @SamiBenRomdhane and others who contributed). The translation also fixed the problem statement appearing only in the title (it should be fully stated in the body of the Question as well).

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici since not everyone can write English, and since there are a large number of MSE users willing to translate non-English questions, I think (as the top-voted post on my link suggested) we ought to welcome translateable non-English posts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equation of tangent to the curve $C$ on the point $(x_0,f(x_0))$ is

$$y=f(x_0)+(x-x_0)f'(x_0)\tag1$$ and the tangent is parallel to the line $d$ iff

$$f'(x_0)=4x_0^2+4x_0+3=2\iff(2x_0+1)^2=0\iff x_0=-\frac12$$
now replace $x_0$ by its value in $(1)$ and we are done.

**Traduction**

L'équation de la tangente à la courbe $C$ en le point $(x_0,f(x_0))$ est

$$y=f(x_0)+(x-x_0)f'(x_0)\tag1$$ et cette tangente est parallèle à la droie $d$ ssi

$$f'(x_0)=4x_0^2+4x_0+3=2\iff(2x_0+1)^2=0\iff x_0=-\frac12$$
maintenant remplace $x_0$ par sa valeur trouvée en $(1)$ et on a terminé.

Comment: Wow formidable !

Comment: y=2x+41/6. Thanks!

Comment: De rien;-)${}{}$

Comment: @SamiBenRomdhane. One more surprize from you ! What don't you know ? Cheers et merci.

Comment: Well... I don't know everything:-) Merci! @ClaudeLeibovici